# AJAX Syntax Error on XMLHttpRequest.send()

Tags: javascript, ajax, syntax

I'm working through [an AJAX tutorial](http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/JSON_AJAX_Web_Chat-.html).  I have little web experience, so I was a bit surprised when something went wrong and I got no traceback, no log, nothing.

I pulled out Firebug and it says I have a syntax error on both of my `send()` calls.

The relevant (I think) parts of the code:

```
function getChatText() {
    if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {
        receiveReq.open("GET", 'getChat.php?chat=1&last=' + lastMessage, true);
        receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleReceiveChat; 
        receiveReq.send(null);  // <---  Firebug says an error is here
    }           
}

function sendChatText() {
    if (sendReq.readyState == 4 || sendReq.readyState == 0) {
        sendReq.open("POST", 'getChat.php?chat=1&last=' + lastMessage, true);
        sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        sendReq.onreadystatechange = handleSendChat;
        var param = 'message=' + document.getElementById('txt_message').value;
        param += '&name=John Doe';
        param += '&chat=1';
        sendReq.send(param);  // <--- and also here
    }
}
```

I've even went so far as to copy/paste these functions from the working tutorial, but I still get the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

The exact error text is:

```
Syntax Error: 
    getChatText()       (line 38)
    handleSendChat()    (line 56)
receiveReq.send(null);  (line 38)
```

Comment: That's not a _syntax_ error.  What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: I **highly** suggest using jQuery for AJAX-related tasks. It simplifies the code ten times over and is more cross-browser compatible. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @SLaks: I didn't think it was, but that's what the error says.  I have added the error message.

Comment: @Dutchie432: jQuery's download link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're error is occurring inside of `getChatText` (which is at the top of the call stack in the error message).

<strike>You're probably calling `eval` with invalid syntax; you may have forgotten to wrap JSON in parentheses.</strike>

You should use Firebug's debugger to track down the error.

**EDIT**: Try calling `encodeURIComponent` on `lastMessage`; it may help.  (and you should do it anyway to prevent URL injection)

Comment: I posted `getChatText`.  As you can see, I'm not calling `eval`.

Comment: I tried calling `encodeUriComponent` on `lastMessage`.  I got `encodeUriComponent is not defined`. I also tried `encodeUrlComponent` in case the `i` was a typo, but I got `encodeUrlComponent is not defined` also.

Comment: I added a call to `encodeURIComponent`.  I did not receive a `not defined` error, but it did not resolve my original syntax error.

Comment: Turns out my PHP I was calling had the syntax error, which was being given to my request and caught by Firebug.  Thank you for your help.